# Parsing a PHP array into a JavaScript array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I'm trying to parse a PHP multidimensional array into a Javascript array.

So far, I've got:

```
<?php
 foreach ($array as $key => $userArray){

 echo "array[] = array['{$userArray['name']}', {$userArray['count']}, {$userArray['userId']}]; \n";
 }
?>
```

from and array that looks like:

```
$array[] = array(
'name' => 'John Doe',
'userId' => '12',
'count' => '31'
);
```

Thanks,

Comment: Does http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php not do the trick?

Comment: That was not the first thing which came into my head :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)?

```
<?php

  echo 'var array = ' . json_encode( $array );

?>
```

Comment: I've just realised that I can do that. :)

Answer (score 0):

you want `json_encode()`

```
<?php 
    $jsonArray = json_encode($array);
    echo $jsonArray; //outputs {"name": 'John Doe',"userId" : 12, "count" : 31}
?>
```

Comment: gotta be quick in this town!

Answer (score 0):

Utilize the json_encode along with the array_map function to do what you need:

```
echo json_encode(array_map(function($user) 
  return array(
     'name' => $user['name'],
     'userId' => $user['userId'],
     'count' => $user['age']
),$userArray));
```